# Spotlight breaks on queries starting with the letter 'a'

Tags: macos, spotlight

I've complete edited this question as new information has come in, so if the comments seem off-topic, it's my fault.

Spotlight freezes every time I start a query with the letter 'a' and then pause for a second or two.  I can kill the process and it will resume working, but this is repeatable and extremely frustrating.

It's not clear to me if this problem is related to a particular set of files on my machine, or what, and I have no idea how to go about debugging it.  Is there a way, e.g., to pose a verbose spotlight query on the command line to see what files it's looking at when it encounters an error?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there any chance that Spotlight is trying to index a network location? A NAS drive, Windows Server/PC, etc?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  This is a laptop that moves around a lot and I don't mount any network drives on a regular basis.  Although that does give me the idea to try disabling some of the individual result types in the Spotlight preferences and to see if any make a difference.  I'll report back about that.